# Python boolean Toggle

Tags: python, keyboard, toggle, pyautogui

I want to make an auto clicker, but I have the problem that my toggle script doesn't work. if I press the key once, it starts. when I press it again nothing happens. I'm not really a good python programmer and I am clueless about what is wrong.

Here is my Script:

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui

Running = False
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("F2"):
        if Running:
            Running = False
        elif Running == False:
            Running = True
    
    if Running:
        pyautogui.click()
    if keyboard.is_pressed("t"):
        exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui

Running = 0
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("F2"):
        Running ^= 1 # if Running is 0 it will become 1. If it's 1 it will become 0
    
    if Running:
        pyautogui.click()
    if keyboard.is_pressed("t"):
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `not` operator in Python

```py
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("F2"):
            Running = not Running
```